# No dSYMs were found for Version x.x.x

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I am getting the Crashlytics detected a missing dSYM for version 1.2.1 error.
I got No dSYMs were found for Version 1.2.1 when I was trying to get the dsym file from xcode.

I was trying to get the dsym file from app store -> testflight -> Build Metadata -> includes symbols, but there have no download button just Yes there.

so I did some search and was trying to download the dysm file from xcode, Follow the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0), and then got the Archive successfully, but when I try to download the debug symbols and get the error "No dSYMs were found for Version 1.2.1". Could someone give me some advice how to solve this problem? I didn't find someone with the same error as me.

Following is my build options setting:
[xcode build option setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3eky.png)
This is the error I got:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa3zJ.png)

Comment: Try following the steps from this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74607068/4044241 When the dSYMs cannot be found, sometimes is better to do these steps to generate new dSYMs.

Comment: I have the 'Debug Information Format' set to 'DWARF with dSYM File' for all your build types... and still trying to download dsym using 'Download debug symbols' from archive produces above error (No dSYMs were found for Version x.x Build yyy). 
Any other thought or suggestion that could help please ?

Comment: im having the same exact issue... checking on the comments first answer ...